# select from system$stream_has_data returns error - parameter must be a valid stream name... hmm?

Tags: stream, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to see if there is data in a stream and I provided the exact stream name as follows :

Select SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('STRM_EXACT_STREAM_NAME_GIVEN');

But, I get an error :

SQL compilation error: Invalid value ['STRM_EXACT_STREAM_NAME_GIVEN'] for function 'SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA', parameter 1: must be a valid stream name

1) Any idea why ? How can this error be resolved ?

2) Would it hurt to resume a set of tasks (alter task  resume;) without knowing if the corresponding stream has data in it or not? I blv if there is (delta) data in the stream, the task will load it, if not, the task won't do anything.

3) Any idea how to modify / update a stream that shows up as 'STALE' ? - or should just loading fresh data into the table associated with the stream should set the stream as 'NOT STALE' i.e. stale = false ? what if loading the associated table does not update the state of the task? (and that is what is happening currently in my case, as things appear.

Answer (score 0):

1) It doesn't look like you have a stream by that name.  Try running `SHOW STREAMS;` to see what streams you have active in the database/schema that you are currently using.

2) If your task has a WHEN clause that validates against the SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA result, then resuming a task and letting it run on schedule only hits against your global services layer (no warehouse credits), so there is no harm there.

3) STALE means that the stream data wasn't used by a DML statement in a long time (I think its 14 days by default or if data retention is longer than 14 days, then it's the longer of those).  Loading more data into the stream table doesn't help that.  Running a DML statement will, but since the stream is stale, doing so may have bad consequences.  Streams are meant to be used for frequent DML, so not running DML against a stream for longer than 14 days is very uncommon.

Comment: Thanks Mike!

Not sure what changed in a couple of hours, the select system$stream_has_data statements that were erroring out earlier, are running fine now. I have 3 tasks and the names of the tasks were exactly the same. However, the error is now gone and I get the boolean result as 'FALSE' for all the 3 streams.

Yes, the default is 14 days.

So, now, since the streams have no data (based on the result 'FASLSE') - it should still be ok to alter the associated tasks to 'resume'. Sounds right ?

Comment: Thanks Mike!

Not sure what changed in a couple of hours, the select system$stream_has_data statements that were erroring out earlier, are running fine now. I have 3 tasks and the names of the tasks were exactly the same. However, the error is now gone and I get the boolean result as 'FALSE' for all the 3 streams.

Yes, the default is 14 days.So, now, since the streams have no data (based on the result 'FASLSE') - it should still be ok to alter the associated tasks to 'resume'. Sounds right ? Also, since the tasks are not running - it should be ok to run the SQL statements manually.Rt?